# Is there performance difference between using sortDescriptors when retrieving from coreData vs. Array.sort?

Tags: swift, core-data

Between 2 methods of getting a sorted array of NSManagedObject, which one is better? Or is there any performance difference between them?

```
/// Method 1: - use sortDescriptors
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.birthday), ascending: true)]
let results = try? coreDataStore.execute(fetchRequest)
return results as? [Person] ?? []

/// Method 2: - use Array.sort() on the returned result
let sortedPeople = results.sort({ ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

Core Data is optimized for performance. Sorting in Core Data is faster.